# Rmpi program hangs after producing correct output. How do I exit programatically?

Tags: r, mpi, distributed-computing, hpc, snow

The code I am using is:

```
library(Rmpi)
mpi.spawn.Rslaves(nslaves=mpi.universe.size()-1)
mpi.remote.exec(paste(--))
mpi.close.Rslaves()
mpi.quit()
```

I tried `mpi.exit()` but still, it hangs.